# If statements involving Radiobuttons

Tags: c#

I'm currently creating a calculator type form on C#. I have four radiobuttons (Addition, subtraction, multi, and div) and a label in between two textboxes. The label changes according to the selected radiobutton, (for example if I selected the Addition radiobutton the label would read "+"). The problem I'm experiencing with this code:

```
    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            label3.Text = ("+");
        }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            label3.Text = ("-");

        }

        else if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
        {
            label3.Text = ("x");

        }

        else if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
        {
            label3.Text = ("/");
        }

    }
```

is when I select the division button the label does not change unless I go through all the buttons and THEN other radio buttons (such as subtraction), when selected, do not change the label until multiple tries. I tried changing the last line to an "else label3.text=("/");" but it doesn't really change anything other than the order of errors.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Just as an aside, `if (radioButton1.Checked == true)` can be shortened to `if (radioButton1.Checked)`.  Same thing, less typing, less to read.

Comment: Can you provide us more code? Additionally, you are calling this code when radioButton1 is changed. Maybe your radioButton4 is not associated with radioButton1?

Comment: Couldn't you wire all 4 radio buttons onto the same method call?

Comment: are the radiobuttons in a group?  So that only one can be checked at a given time?  I'm kind of confused by your explanation

Comment: also are all radiobuttons linked to that event

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to check if the radio button is checked in each individual radioButtonX_CheckedChanged method like so:

```
    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            label3.Text = ("+");
        }
    }

    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            label3.Text = ("-");
        }
    }

    private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton3.Checked)
        {
            label3.Text = ("x");
        }
    }

    private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton4.Checked)
        {
            label3.Text = ("/");
        }
    }
```

Let me know if that helps, and if you are still having the issue.

Comment: comparing a boolean variable to `true` is superfluous. you can just write `if (radioButton1.checked) [...]`

Comment: @JacobAbrahams indeed, I was just replicating his code, I will edit. Good comment!

Comment: Your idea is right, but he could as well just assign he same method to all his radiobuttons CheckedChange and keep one method.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren True, but I think it is more efficient to have them in separate event methods, considering it would be more load on the cpu to process (waste of resources) those extra conditional statements if you are selecting the multiplication / division operator.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change how you check for the Checked button. MrB's solution works, but if you'd like to keep your selection code in a single block (as you have), make sure all your radio buttons have their CheckedChanged event subscribed to something similar to the following:

```
private void RadioButtonCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var radioButton = (RadioButton)sender;

    if (radioButton.Checked)
    {
        switch (radioButton.Text)
        {
            case "Add":
                label3.Text = "+";
                break;
            case "Subtract":
                label3.Text = "-";
                break;
            case "Divison":
                label3.Text = "/";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also switch on another property, such as the `RadioButton.Tag` field, whatever may be meaningful to you.

As far as the actual reason your code is failing, it's hard to understand without ensuring which RadioButton's have their events set properly, and seeing the incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        agm.Visible = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "1" ? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.